# Converting a list of Characters to a list of numbers

Tags: python, list

How can I convert this list `['c','c','c','c','c','h','h','h','h','h','e','e','e','e','e']`
to this `[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2]`

Comment: What would the output be for `['y','y','y','z','z','z','x','x','x']` be? Would it still be `[0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2]` or is this input even valid for your program?

Comment: For `['c','c','h','h','e','e','c']`, would you want `[0,0,1,1,2,2,0]` or `[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]`?  (It's actually kind of funny how poorly constrained this question is -- several people have given perfectly valid but different interpretations of what you want.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a bit unclear, is this what you're after?

```
In [2]: conv={'c':0,'h':1,'e':2}

In [3]: a=['c','c','c','c','c','h','h','h','h','h','e','e','e','e','e']

In [4]: [conv[i] for i in a]
Out[4]: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use string.maketrans, and string.translate to do something similar:

```
>>> import string
>>> t = string.maketrans("che", "012")
>>> test_str = "ccccchhhhheeeee"
>>> string.translate(test_str, t)
'000001111122222'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is very unclear. Assuming you want to do some operation on the original to get the output a good bet would be map. You can pass in any function you want which somehow converts it based on your preference

```
>>> a = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> converted = map(lambda x: ord(x), a)
>>> print converted
[97, 98, 99]
```

Basic idea is you pass in a function to map which will act on each element in the original list and convert it. For example to get the alphabetical value of each letter we could do write the lambda function as `lambda x : ord(char.lower()) - 96`

Eg:

```
>>> a = ["a", "b", "c"]  
>>> converted = map(lambda x : ord(x.lower()) - 96 , a)
>>> print converted
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: If you notice, then the numbers are no where relared to the ordinal, but their order in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is very underspecified, but if my wild guess happens to land, then maybe something like:

```
>>> s = ['c','c','c','c','c','h','h','h','h','h','e','e','e','e','e']
>>> from itertools import groupby, chain
>>> counted = enumerate(len(list(g)) for k,g in groupby(s))
>>> list(chain.from_iterable([i]*c for i,c in counted))
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

would give you what you want?  This uses `groupby` to collect neighbouring contiguous terms:

```
>>> [(k, list(g)) for k,g in groupby(s)]
[('c', ['c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']), ('h', ['h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h']), ('e', ['e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e'])]
>>> [len(list(g)) for k,g in groupby(s)]
[5, 5, 5]
```

and `enumerate` to count them:

```
>>> list(enumerate(len(list(g)) for k,g in groupby(s)))
[(0, 5), (1, 5), (2, 5)]
```

and finally `chain` to recombine them in flattened form:

```
>>> [[i]*c for i, c in enumerate(len(list(g)) for k,g in groupby(s))]
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable([[i]*c for i, c in enumerate(len(list(g)) for k,g in groupby(s))]))
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```